# How to find largest amount based on entity within group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say my DataFrame looks something like this:

```
Bank  Entity  Amount
JPM   NY      5000
JPM   NY      300
BOA   LA      10000
BOA   China   3000
MS    Japan   21000
```

I would like to output based on top entity, while keeping in mind that the Bank is different, so the DataFrame then becomes:

```
Bank  Entity  Amount
JPM   NY      5000
BOA   LA      10000
MS    Japan   21000
```

How would I go about creating something like this? I know how to `sort_values` and also `group_by` but I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's super simple.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indexes of max values and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Bank')['Amount'].idxmax()]
print (df)
  Bank Entity  Amount
2  BOA     LA   10000
0  JPM     NY    5000
4   MS  Japan   21000
```

Or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first and then use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('Amount').groupby('Bank', as_index=False).last()
print (df)
  Bank Entity  Amount
0  BOA     LA   10000
1  JPM     NY    5000
2   MS  Japan   21000
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!

Comment: To you as well - you are the only reason I had as productive of a week as I did.